# Angularjs handle custom added input field after submission of form

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am new to use angularjs. I have an app that have a custom drag drop form functionality. When i submit the form and clear form after submission the dynamic generated input box are bot removing form scope.
Ok i just create a sample example of my problem so i can describe it in simple.

Here is my html file :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            <form ng-submit="myForm(theForm.$valid)" name="theForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div id="container"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="addForm()" value="Add">
        <pre>{{theForm | json}}</pre>
        <table border="2">
            <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
                <td>{{record.name}}</td>
                <td>{{record.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script src="jquery.1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for this html file i have a app.js file where i declare module controller and create a directive for adding a form dynamically.Here is the complete app.js file code :-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl' , function($scope, $compile){

    var data = [];
    $scope.records = data;

    $scope.addForm = function(){
        $compile($('#container').html('<div class="my-form"></div>'))($scope);
    };
    $scope.myForm = function(valid){
        if(valid){
            data.push($scope.form);
            $scope.form = null;
            $('.my-form').remove();
        }
        else{
            console.log('invalid form');
        }

    };
})
.directive('myForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="maincontainer"><div class="namefield"><input type="text" required="required" name="name" ng-model="form.name"></div><div class="agefield" id="other_field"><input name="age" required="required" type="text" ng-model="form.age"></div><div class="buttons"><input type="submit" value="submit"><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addMore()"></div></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $compile){
            var id = 1;
            $scope.addMore = function(){
                var html = '<div><input name="other'+id+'" required="required" type="text" ng-model="form.text'+id+'"></div>';
                var oldhtml = $('#other_field').html();
                oldhtml+=html;
                $compile($('#other_field').html(oldhtml))($scope);
                id++;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Description of this code :-

This code generate a simple form with 2 input fields and after that i can add one more field to it. Submit this form and clear form field and remove this form. And we can add more records by adding it once again.

Now if i add a form and submit the form without adding more input field then it works properly.

But anytime if i add 3rd input box or i add one more input box then it will submitted. But after that i add once again new form and this time i am not adding new input box and now i submit this form it will not submitted. Becoz last time generated 3rd input form is still in scope. So form says that it will require.

So how can i completely remove this generated form so i can receive fresh form with 2 fields next time.

[Check this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajWb5rNW0RupnLXK9Xvf?p=preview)

Comment: Get rid of all that jQuery and use your data model to generate the view. Should be pushing objects to arrays and using `ng-repeat`. Create a demo that can be forked

Comment: here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/ajWb5rNW0RupnLXK9Xvf?p=preview @charlietfl

Comment: basic working example...submit will copy to saved items  http://plnkr.co/edit/ejsdt3D3PnlQoZtcXyPq?p=preview

Comment: thanks for reply.but my problem is not solve from this.u have 2 fields in this example name and age..when u click add button dont add whole form again..just add one more sibling to name and age. so form looks like Name, Age and Otherfield. And then submit it. And next time only submit form with Name and Age field. Then u see the changes. @charlietfl

Comment: Well your demo had no labels so wasn't clear. I you need another property add it to the object. Not 100% clear how it is supposed to work. Just one record in form? With multiple properties?

Comment: yes i need to add one more record in form. and submit it. next time u submit form with only defult form or that time dont add new property. But this time form still needed the last time added property. @charlietfl

Comment: hopefully you can see the angular way better now and can adapt to add a property instead. I made array of people objects but you need array of properties in a single person